# Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'req_dt' at row in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am working on mysql stored procedure it executes the call statement with the 
  following parametrs

```
CALL GetAbsentReportData('2011-11-01','2011-11-30',3);
```

It shows an error for this statement

```
CALL GetAbsentReportData('2013-04-01','2013-05-01',1) ;
```

Error is

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'req_dt' at row 1    
0.374 sec
```

Please help me how to resolve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Too much information. Did you read [faq] ?

Comment: You should paste what your procedure does, and what the req_dt column type is.

Comment: There is no req_dt field

Answer (score 2):

1. You server use [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) mode.
2. Table `emp_leaves` has `req_dt` field. Some records of this table has 0000-00-00 in those field. This query tells me about

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMPLVDATA AS
   select * from emp_leaves where leave_txn_code = 'ABS' and from_dt >= fromDate and to_dt <= toDate order by to_dt desc

So you can disable this mode. Read documentation about [MySQL modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html). Or change you select query.

Comment: I Solved my Problem, by default in my table few records have the req_dt is in 0000-00-00 just update that date and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved my Problem, by default in my table few records have the req_dt is in 0000-00-00 just update that date and it is working fine.